# Lotus Notes : Not able to access properties file in lotuscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Hi friends i want to access the properties file from machine from the specified path. For java Agent i used Properties method and extracted the data from the properties file. but now i want it to be done in lotuscript. I tried using properties method but it didnt work so i thought to read properties with the below code.

```
'Dim ColFileName As String
    'ColFileName="C:\abcd.properties"
    Open ColFileName For Input As 1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1,txt$
    MsgBox "TEXT FILE:"+txt$
```

In properties file i have a written it as 
col=start

where i want to get the property of the col using getProperty method in java same way for lotusscript. 
I added the above code but it is not working. Can anyone tell what mistake i have committed.

Comment: Hi , check the runlevel of your agent it should be at least 2. And have a look at the NotesStream class.....

Comment: Could you show us a little Java code where you use the getProperty method? For I cannot find the methods you're referring to...

Comment: Please define what you mean by "is not working". Explain exactly what is happening, or not happening that you expected to happen. Is there an error message? What is the msgbox displaying? Also, please confirm whether this is an agent or event code in the Notes client, and explain exactly how you are running the code. E.g., are you running it locally in your client, on schedule on the server, triggered by a web URL, etc?

Comment: @D.Bugger how can i add the java code in lotusscript file

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Just need to ask whether i can parse the properties file in lotusscript is there any method like properties method in java  and i what to get the property file from lotus script

Comment: Use the LotusScipt Debugger.

Comment: or @D.Bugger can you let me know how to read the above file

Comment: "not working" is not a valid error description: Where should the code run, what does is do? Answer the questions Richard asked you... don't just open another thread just because you are bored by this one...

Comment: No,@LotusWorst, there is no method built into LotusScript for parsing Java property files. You will have to write your own parsing code using LotusScript's string handling capabilities.

Comment: Or use LS2J... See http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tips.nsf/0/27e4a1c9f2365f20852571e0004ce4f2?OpenDocument&ExpandSection=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Options

```
%Include "lserr.lss" 'This is just a list of constants.
```

Add these functions somewhere:

```
%REM
    Function fstreamOpenFile(sPath As String, bTruncate As Boolean, bConfirmExists As Boolean) As NotesStream
    <dl>
    <dt>sPath</dt><dd>Filepath of the file to be opened/created.</dd>
    <dt>bTruncate</dt><dd>Boolean. True if file is for output and any existing file should be replaced rather than appended to.</dd>
    <dt>bConfirmExists</dt><dd>Boolean. If True, and the opened file is empty, then an ErrFileNotFound error will be thrown.</dd>
    </dl>
%END REM
Function fstreamOpenFile(sPath As String, bTruncate As Boolean, bConfirmExists As Boolean) As NotesStream
    Dim session as New NotesSession     Dim stream As NotesStream

    Set stream = session.Createstream()
    If Not stream.Open(sPath) Then Error ErrOpenFailed, {Could not open file at "} + sPath + {"}
    If bConfirmExists And stream.Bytes = 0 Then Error ErrFileNotFound, {File at "} + sPath + {" is missing or empty.} 
    If bTruncate Then Call stream.Truncate()
    Set fstreamOpenFile = stream
End Function

Function fsPropertyFileValue(sFilePath As String, sPropertyName As String, sDefaultValue As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorQuietly
    Dim stream As NotesStream
    Dim sLine As String
    Dim sLeft As String
    Dim iLeftLen As Integer

    Set stream = fstreamOpenFile(sFilePath, False, True)
    sLeft = sPropertyName + "="
    iLeftLen = Len(sLeft)
    Do
        sLine = stream.Readtext
        If Left(sLine, iLeftLen) = sLeft Then
            fsPropertyFileValue = Right(sLine, Len(sLine) - iLeftLen)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop Until stream.Iseos
ReturnDefault:
    fsPropertyFileValue = sDefaultValue
    Exit Function
ErrorQuietly:
    Print Now, Error$
    Resume ReturnDefault
End Function
```

*(Notes: I have not tested/debugged fsPropertyFileValue. The html tags in the comment is because, when editing an agent or script library, the designer client will parse and display the HTML tags.)*

Then you can use `fsPropertyFileValue("C:\abcd.properties", "col", "start")` to get the value of the col property within C:\abcd.properties and, if that fails, use "start".